# -[NSParagraphStyle isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702b2480 in iOS10.3

Tags: ios10.3

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph=[[NSMutableParagraphStyle 
defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];

[paragraph setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:FONT_14, NSFontAttributeName, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraph,nil];
CGRect nvoiceStateSize = [tips boundingRectWithSize:line3size
                                 options:(NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin| NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                              attributes:attrs
                                 context:nil];
```

it crashed when excute boundingRectWithSize:

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what the type of `tips` is, but I'm gonna go on a limb and bet it is _not_ a class that implements `-boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari a lucky guess, perhaps...